# Export ASP Image control to a folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I have an **ASP Image control** that I want to save to a specific folder.

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "~/fa/barcode.aspx?d=" + Label1.Text.ToUpper();
```

This is basically what **barcode.aspx** does:

```
 Bitmap oBitmap = new Bitmap(w, 100);

        // then create a Graphic object for the bitmap we just created.
        Graphics oGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(oBitmap);

        oGraphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.None;
        oGraphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixel;


        // Let's create the Point and Brushes for the barcode
        PointF oPoint = new PointF(2f, 2f);
        SolidBrush oBrushWrite = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        SolidBrush oBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);

        // Now lets create the actual barcode image
        // with a rectangle filled with white color
        oGraphics.FillRectangle(oBrush, 0, 0, w, 100);

        // We have to put prefix and sufix of an asterisk (*),
        // in order to be a valid barcode
        oGraphics.DrawString("*" + Code + "*", oFont, oBrushWrite, oPoint);
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
oBitmap.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

How do I save it to a folder (**~/fa/barcodeimages/**)? So far here's what I tried:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
                string remote = "http://" + Request.Url.Authority.ToString() + "/fa/barcode.aspx?d=" + Label1.Text.ToUpper();
                string local = Server.MapPath("barcodeimages/" + Label1.Text.ToUpper() + ".jpeg");
                webClient.DownloadFile(remote, local);
```

But it does not work, I always get a corrupted .jpeg file. And it seems inefficient.

Comment: You haven't explained where `oBitmap` comes from - or what you really mean by "saving" an image control. Where is the image data itself, and what exactly are you trying to save?

Comment: @JonSkeet It's actually a barcode image. I edited the post to include the code. What I wanted to do is copy/export that Image to a folder of my website. So the result would be having a file in the website folder: (~/fa/barcodeimages/barcode1.jpeg).

Comment: @PodMays: If you type in the URL in the browser, does it render the jpeg right? If not, the problem is with the way bitmap is constructed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that your business logic - the code required to generate a barcode image - is in the wrong place.

You should keep that business logic away from the *presentation* logic of your aspx page (which is about serving an image to respond to a URL), and move the `Bitmap` creation logic to somewhere that both the "serve a barcode" and "save a barcode to disk" code can get at it. That could be in a different business logic assembly, or it could simply be in a separate class within the same project. The main thing is that you want it in a reusable place.

At that point, your aspx code changes to something like:

```
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
using (Bitmap bitmap = barcodeGenerator.Generate(Code))
{
    bitmap.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

and your saving code changes to something like:

```
// TODO: Validate that the text here doesn't contain dots, slashes etc
string code = Label1.Text.ToUpper();
string file = Server.MapPath("barcodeimages/" + code + ".jpeg");
using (Bitmap bitmap = barcodeGenerator.Generate(code))
{
    bitmap.Save(file, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

Here, `barcodeGenerator` would ideally be a depedency-injected instance of your `BarcodeGenerator` class (or whatever it turns out to be). If you're not using dependency injection, you could create a new instance directly, specifying the font etc each time - it's not as pleasant, but it should work okay.

Comment: Hi, the barcode generation code is actually in Barcode.aspx (Page_Load). And I call it with `Image1.ImageUrl = "~/fixedasset/GenerateBarcodeImage.aspx?d=" + Label1.Text.ToUpper();` on (Page1.aspx).

Comment: @PodMays: But that's my point - it would be better *not* to have it in a presentation layer.